# My IE developer tool indicates that my Community site (Discussion forum) page have received 5.56 MB when clearing the browser cache

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, javascript, performance, performancepoint

I have built a community site inside my SharePoint 2013 server. and on the discussion forum home page , I have captured the network for the page using IE developer tool. and it shows that it have revived 5.56 MB when I do  a hard refresh for the browser as follow:-

[image]

And if I refresh the page again it will receive only 230 KB,as it seems that most components were cached.
So is having 5.56 MB for an intranet community site will cause performance problems ? and most of the bandwidth were used for a SharePoint core components and scripts which I did not actually add, such as sp.js, sp.ui.rte.js, .js, etc ?

So can anyone advice if I am having something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

As you say yourself, most of the files are SharePoint standard files, that will be downloaded when the user first hits SharePoint and then a cached version will be used.

So in your case I think the Delta between a blank Community site and your modified one will be the best indication on if your modifications are "too heavy"

(As a reference, the Portal landing page in the project I work on now right now weighs in at 4.1 MB when "cold started", no cached data. On the second load, with cached data, it is only 180 KB).

Comment: so you mean i am on the safe side, with 5.6 MB and 230 KB ?

Comment: I say most of the data seems to be OOTB SharePoint files (or prerequisites to your solution if you want to see it like that), so it is no abnormally large figure!

Comment: i created a test community site which does not have members or discussions, and the network will be 0.91 MB only. the main differences between my real site and the test site, is that the real site have members and discussions. but i have also noted that some scripts did not download when creating a new community site such as  sp.js, sp.ui.rte.js, .js ? can these scripts fires only if there is discussions and members ?

Comment: Of course the content will matter, as you say. If there is no information to handle, SharePoint will not have to load some of the resources. The majority of JavaScript in SharePoint 2013 is loaded on demand, as part of the minimal download strategy :)

Comment: but at the end will having 5 MB to download an indication of a performance problem ?

Comment: This is dependent on the situation, inhouse with network speeds of 100Mbps or above this is not a problem. But if it is a public page, that people do not work on on a daily basis, surely they will notice a delay on the first load. I would say it is up to your client to test and decide if this is good enough.

Comment: it is an intranet but can be accessed from outside the company network using VPN .

Comment: My answer still stands